# React redux - change property on individual state item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have a reducer with a list of characters. This list gets displayed in another component in the app. However, there is also a separate container that has an SVG illustration of various characters. The individual characters in the illustration have an id attribute that corresponds with the id property in the characters array seen here:

**reducers/reduce_characters.js**

```
export default function(state =  null, action) {
    var characters = [
        { 
            id: '_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell',
            name: 'Stringer Bell', 
            found: false
        },
        { 
            id: '_x31_1-A-JimmyMcNulty',
            name: 'Jimmy McNulty', 
            found: false
        }
    ];

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'BOARD_CLICKED':

        // here we will update the found property of the item in characters array with matching ID

    }

    return characters;
}
```

action.payload equals the id of the element clicked. in the action creator, I want to loop through the characters array and set the found property to true if the id is equal to that of the element clicked (in this case, the value of action.payload)

**actions/index.js**

```
export function boardClicked(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);

    return {
        type: 'BOARD_CLICKED',
        payload: event.target.id
    };
}
```

I'm very new to React, feel like this shouldn't be that difficult, but want to figure out the best way to do this the React/Redux "way" and update the state accordingly.

Here is my container as well:

**containers/board.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SVGInline from "react-svg-inline";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { boardClicked } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Board extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="board" onClick={(event) => this.props.boardClicked(event)}>
                <SVGInline svg={'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2500 2623" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2500 2623;" xml:space="preserve"><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="2500" height="2624" id="Background_1_" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C05349.jpeg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 0.9996 0 0.5)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="2500" height="1876" id="Illustration" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C0534B.jpeg" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 185)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="164" id="_x30_1-B-RussellStringerBell" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C05349.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 728 686)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="164" id="_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C0534F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 728 686)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="102" height="144" id="_x30_2-B-Kenard" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C0534A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1322 869)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="102" height="151" id="_x30_2-A-Kenard" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C0534B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1322 862)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="86" height="144" id="_x30_3-B-MarloStanfield" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C05346.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 570 1274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="86" height="144" id="_x30_3-A-MarloStanfield" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C05347.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 570 1274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="79" height="132" id="_x30_4-B-CalvinCheeseWagstaff" xlink:href="/img/2A6DA3D578C05359.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2 1556)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="79" height="132" id="_x30_4-A-CalvinCheeseWagstaff" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0992.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2 1556)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="138" height="207" id="_x30_5-B-MauriceLevy" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0995.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 600 1695)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="138" height="207" id="_x30_5-A-MauriceLevy" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0996.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 600 1695)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="100" height="165" id="_x30_6-B-SpirosVondasVondopoulos" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0994.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 289 1394)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="100" height="165" id="_x30_6-A-SpirosVondasVondopoulos" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0993.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 289 1394)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="195" id="_x30_7-B-The_Greek" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC098D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 192 1373)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="195" id="_x30_7-A-The_Greek" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC098E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 192 1373)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="180" id="_x30_8-B-PropositionJoe" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC098C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 527 565)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="174" height="181" id="_x30_8-A-PropositionJoe" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09B2.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 527 564)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="140" height="161" id="_x30_9-B-BriannaBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09B5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1142 605)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="149" height="175" id="_x30_9-A-BriannaBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09A9.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1133 591)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="186" id="_x31_0-B-DeLondaBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09AB.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 253 1243)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="186" id="_x31_0-A-DeLondaBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09A8.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 253 1243)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="186" height="376" id="_x31_1-B-JayLandsman" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09D7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1989 915)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="186" height="376" id="_x31_1-A-JayLandsman" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09D9.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1989 915)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="109" height="247" id="_x31_2-B-AvonBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09DB.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 450 1338)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="109" height="247" id="_x31_2-A-AvonBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09D8.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 450 1338)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="190" id="_x31_3-B-BeadieRussell" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09DF.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1583 1673)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="197" id="_x31_3-A-BeadieRussell" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09DA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1575 1666)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="139" height="350" id="_x31_4-B-WilliamRawls" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09E6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1694 1597)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="139" height="351" id="_x31_4-A-WilliamRawls" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09FC.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1694 1596)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="99" height="194" id="_x31_5-B-NickSobotka" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C3.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 315 1867)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="99" height="194" id="_x31_5-A-NickSobotka" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C4.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 315 1867)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="309" id="_x31_6-B-ClarenceRoyce" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1185 1736)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="324" id="_x31_6-A-ClarenceRoyce" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1185 1721)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="152" height="217" id="_x31_7-B-TommyCarcetti" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C2.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2217 1844)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="154" height="219" id="_x31_7-A-TommyCarcetti" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09CC.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2215 1842)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="152" id="_x31_8-B-ThomasKlebanow" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09CF.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1917 1909)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="127" height="153" id="_x31_8-A-ThomasKlebanow" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09CD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1917 1908)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="137" height="153" id="_x31_9_x5F_B-ScottTempleton" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC09C1.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1823 1908)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="137" height="153" id="_x31_9_x5F_A-ScottTempleton" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1823 1908)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="108" height="193" id="_x32_0-B-ClayDavis" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A21.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1589 553)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="108" height="193" id="_x32_0-A-ClayDavis" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A23.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1589 553)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="236" id="_x32_1-B-ChrisPartlow" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A26.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 413 1070)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="236" id="_x32_1-A-ChrisPartlow" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A27.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 413 1070)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="145" id="_x32_2-B-SnoopPearson" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A22.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2015 462)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="145" id="_x32_2-A-SnoopPearson" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2015 462)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="66" height="107" id="_x32_3-B-RolandPryzbylewski" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 158 1660)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="66" height="107" id="_x32_3-A-RolandPryzbylewski" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 158 1660)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="199" id="_x32_4-B-BodieBroadus" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A24.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 892 1331)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="125" height="199" id="_x32_4-A-BodieBroadus" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 892 1331)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="67" height="140" id="_x32_5-B-Wallace" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A19.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1371 663)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="67" height="140" id="_x32_5-A-Wallace" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1371 663)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="248" id="_x32_6-B-WilliamBunkMoreland" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A18.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1951 1698)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="171" height="248" id="_x32_6-A-WilliamBunkMoreland" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A06.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1951 1698)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="292" id="_x32_7-B-DukieWeems" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A09.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1482 1174)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="292" id="_x32_7-A-DukieWeems" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1482 1174)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="291" id="_x32_8-B-RandyWagstaff" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A08.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1424 1109)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="106" height="291" id="_x32_8-A-RandyWagstaff" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1424 1109)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="246" id="_x32_9-B-MichaelLee" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A0B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1281 1129)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="246" id="_x32_9-A-MichaelLee" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A6D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1281 1129)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="223" id="_x33_0-B-NamondBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A6F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1342 1098)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="115" height="223" id="_x33_0-A-NamondBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A6C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1342 1098)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="97" height="248" id="_x33_1-B-FrankSobotka" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A6B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1789 483)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="97" height="248" id="_x33_1-A-FrankSobotka" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A15.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1789 483)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="90" height="248" id="_x33_2-B-RhondaPearlman" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A17.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1955 296)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="90" height="248" id="_x33_2-A-RhondaPearlman" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A14.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1955 296)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="117" height="159" id="_x33_3-B-EllisCarver" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1963 1291)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="117" height="159" id="_x33_3-A-EllisCarver" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1963 1291)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="111" height="192" id="_x33_4-B-ThomasHercHauk" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A1F.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1875 1274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="111" height="192" id="_x33_4-A-ThomasHercHauk" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A30.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1875 1274)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="154" id="_x33_5-B-AugustusHaynes" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A3C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2119 1604)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="118" height="154" id="_x33_5-A-AugustusHaynes" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A31.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2119 1604)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="184" id="_x33_6-B-LesterFreamon" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A33.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1658 567)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="184" id="_x33_6-A-LesterFreamon" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A36.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1658 567)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="136" height="200" id="_x33_7-B-CedricDaniels" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A37.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2262 1523)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="136" height="200" id="_x33_7-A-CedricDaniels" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A32.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 2262 1523)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="202" id="_x33_8-B-SlimCharles" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1921 1058)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="202" id="_x33_8-A-SlimCharles" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1921 1058)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="159" id="_x33_9-B-HowardBunnyColvin" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A2C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1050 1902)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="133" height="159" id="_x33_9-A-HowardBunnyColvin" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0ACB.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1050 1902)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="194" height="280" id="_x34_0-B-D_x27_AngeloBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0ACD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 815 742)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="194" height="280" id="_x34_0-A-D_x27_AngeloBarksdale" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0ACF.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 815 742)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="330" id="_x34_1-B-RolandWee-BayBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0ACA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 606 1016)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="330" id="_x34_1-A-RolandWee-BayBrice" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AC9.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 606 1016)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="211" id="_x34_2-B-DennisCuttyWise" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1028 430)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="129" height="211" id="_x34_2-A-DennisCuttyWise" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AF7.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1028 430)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="264" id="_x34_3-B-KimaGreggs" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1974 728)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="120" height="264" id="_x34_3-A-KimaGreggs" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFB.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1974 728)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="161" id="_x34_4-B-ReginaldBubblesCousins" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AFD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10 1785)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="161" id="_x34_4-A-ReginaldBubblesCousins" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9A.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10 1785)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="365" id="_x34_5-B-BrotherMouzone" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9D.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1602 1019)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="122" height="365" id="_x34_5-A-BrotherMouzone" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9E.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1602 1019)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="144" height="283" id="_x34_6-B-JimmyMcNulty" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9C.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 910 715)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="144" height="283" id="_x34_6-A-JimmyMcNulty" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0A9B.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 910 715)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="185" id="_x34_7-B-OmarLittle" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA5.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1289 1291)"></image><image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new ;" width="126" height="185" id="_x34_7-A-OmarLittle" xlink:href="/img/21D8ADDA73CC0AA6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1289 1291)"></image></svg>'} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.characters.map((character) => {
            if(character.found === true) {
                document.getElementById(character.id).style.display = 'none';
            }   
        });
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        characters: state.characters
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // Whenever selectCharacter is called, the result should be passed to all reducers
    return bindActionCreators({ boardClicked: boardClicked }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you're right, this isn't too hard to do in React/Redux. Are your initial characters always the same? You can look at passing them into your store as an initalState parameter, but in the meantime, I would pull them out of my reducer and pass them in like so:

```
const characters = [
        { 
            id: '_x30_1-A-RussellStringerBell',
            name: 'Stringer Bell', 
            found: false
        },
        { 
            id: '_x31_1-A-JimmyMcNulty',
            name: 'Jimmy McNulty', 
            found: false
        }
    ];

export default charactersReducer(state = characters, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'BOARD_CLICKED':
      return state.map((character) => {  // map over the characters, returning a new array
        if (character.id === action.id) { // if character id matches action id, change that character
          return {
            ... character, // this uses the proposed object destructuring, make sure your babel lets you use it
            found: !character.found // this toggles the view, but you could just set it to true
          }
        } else { // if the id doesn't match, return the original character
          return character
        }
      });

    }
    default:
      return state; // return the state, not the characters on default
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work. the property gets updated in state but the UI does not update. how can i re-render the 'board' component?

Comment: @user2994560 look at the `Component.willReceiveNewProps` method.

Comment: oh nevermind, i just had to change what was in the componentDidMount method to componentDidUpdate to update the css